# bash: conditional binary operator expected when checking if a file is readable?

Tags: linux, bash

I have this code that works perfectly on one Macbook but doesn't work on another Linux machine in bash. When run in the Linux machine, I get an error `"conditional binary operator expected"` `"syntax error near` ${testfile}'" when trying to check if the file in the variable is readable or a file.

```
for file in "${@:2}"
do
 if [[ ! -rf ${file} ]]
```

when I make it `[ ! -rf "$file" ]` I get: `[: -rf: unary operator expected`

Comment: `-rf` does indeed seem to work on my MacBook but I have no idea what it's supposed to do, and I get the same error when I try it on a random old Debian box where presumably I have an older version of Bash. What's the actual purpose of this script?

Comment: I'm guessing maybe it's a way to write `[[ ! -r $file -a ! -f $file ]]` which of course then should be portable back to Bash v2 and possibly beyond.

Comment: with this, I get told: `syntax error near `-a' @tripleee

Comment: My bad, that should be `[[ ! -r $file && ! -f $file ]]` but I'm still guessing here. Can you confirm that you are trying to check that the file exists and is a regular file and is readable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[[ ! -r "${file}" && ! -f "${file}" ]]
```

or:

```
[ ! -r "${file}" -a ! -f "${file}" ]
```

Comment: Is there a difference between using -a and not using -a?

Comment: @novel you can't use `-a` with `[[`, you also can't use `&&` with `[`. These solutions are equal.

Comment: Well except that more broadly `[[` is in many ways different than `[`, and often more convenient (e.g. in that it's less demanding when it comes to quoting its arguments).

Answer (score 1):

Just using the **-r** test will work

```
if [[ ! -r ${file} ]]
```